# Slim PHP routes not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've built a Slim PHP app and published it on my webserver.

The routes are only available if I browse directly via the index.php page

for example `example.com/index.php/login` and `/index.php/signup`

both render the expected views

however if I omit index.php and browse to `example.com/login' or 'example.com/signup' I get a 404

My `.htaccess` file is located in the same directory as `index.php`

```
public/
├── .htaccess
├── index.php
```

the `public` folder is configured as the `DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public` in apache

My `.htaccess` file contains the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any suggestions how to fix my routing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slim recommends using these rules for Apache. (.htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Rembember you have to set the **AllowOverride** directive to "All" in the Apache config and make sure that "/public" is your root virtual directory.

Comment: I've got those lines in my `htaccess` file.

Comment: I hadn't edited my `apache2.conf` to `AllowOverride`

Comment: This worked for me but the last line where it says RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]*, I had to remove the asterix * for it to work.